# gcloud auth activate-service-account from JSON to set current project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I created a service account and got a JSON formatted credential file back, which looks like this.

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "myproject",
  "private_key_id": "db0cd27ba7d2acad610b854c04f0aa8ad67ad5fc",
  "private_key": "REDACTED",
  "client_email": "gitlab-ci@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "558691835510594518717",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/gitlab-ci%40myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

I can then activate this service account as follows

```
# gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file myproject-5ddb0cd20b85.json
Activated service account credentials for: [gitlab-ci@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
```

Since the JSON file includes the `project_id`, I expected this to be set in the active configuration, but it isn't.

```
# gcloud config configurations list
NAME     IS_ACTIVE  ACCOUNT                                             PROJECT  DEFAULT_ZONE  DEFAULT_REGION
default  True       gitlab-ci@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Is there some way to set the project from the JSON file when I activate the service account?

Answer (score 1):

The `project_id` from the Service Account JSON file is not supposed to be automatically set as the default project.

Having this functionality depends on the use case. Some API calls are done by using the project_id from the Service Account, and some use the default project currently set, so it wouldn’t be appropriate to generalize this.

As a workaround, I made a bash script that achieves what you’re looking for:

```
gcloud config set project $(cat 'key.json' | jq '.project_id' | sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the JSON file is actually used for authenticating and the project_id is used for authentication purposes, it is  not kept in the active configuration.

Comment: I can see that, but my question is how to how to set the active project from that JSON file. I can't use the service account without the project being set, so it seems like a good idea to be able to set it when activating the account.